# How to select file using AppleScript in Finder prompt?

Tags: applescript, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I am working with Selenium on macOS to automate sending images using WhatsApp web in Google Chrome. The task involves uploading the image, and for that a system(Finder) prompt comes up to select the file. It's done in Windows using [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

I tried looking up how to automate this task in macOS, and I believe AppleScript can be used for it. Since I have no experience in GUI scripting, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't advocate GUI scripting any more than the burning down of the Amazon, but it seems to be necessary for this task, and I wanted to provide you with an example of a GUI script that tries its best to minimise the unpleasantness of the user experience, and aim for fewer weak points in the code where GUI scripts are most likely to falter.

If you know the path to your file—which I assume you do in these sorts of situations, as your script keystrokes the filepath—then you might find the following technique saves a few steps, and feels a bit more graceful in how it gets executed:

```
set filepath to "/path/to/image.jpg"

-- Copy file object to clipboard
set the clipboard to filepath as «class furl»

-- Make sure Chrome is in focus and the
-- active tab is a WhatsApp tab
tell application id "com.google.Chrome"
    activate
    if the URL of the active tab in the front window ¬
        does not contain "web.whatsapp.com" then return
end tell

-- Paste the clipboard contents
-- and hit return (send)
tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents"
    tell (process 1 where it is frontmost) to tell ¬
        menu bar 1 to tell menu bar item "Edit" to tell ¬
        menu 1 to tell menu item "Paste" to set Paste to it

    if (click Paste) = Paste then keystroke return
end tell
```

The `if (click Paste) = Paste` check *should* negate the need for a delay, as it explicitly forces AppleScript to evaluate the `click` command *before* going on to issue a `keystroke`. However, I can't test this under all possible conditions, and if there are other factors, like CPU usage, or process freezes, that are likely to give the script a chance to jump ahead, then just insert a small `delay` after `then` and move `keystroke return` down onto its own line.

If you wish to remove the file object from the clipboard afterwards, then simply add as the final line `set the clipboard to` (and just leave it blank after the word `"to"`, which will clear the clipboard's contents).  Of course, this won't affect any clipboard history data you might have if you use a clipboard managing app, only the system clipboard's current item.

Comment: Far be it for me to critique your code, because frankly, your coding skills far surpasses mine. It did occur to me, however, your code does not factor in the event of a tab (other than the active tab) containing "web.whatsapp.com”.  I took the liberty to play around a bit and came up with this as a solution.
https://pastebin.com/KQpbHCFL

Comment: @wch1zpink I never mind being critiqued, and we all know I hand it out. Your critique is fair and crossed my mind at the time, but I chose to draw the line closer in for "added extras". Even checking the `active tab` was something I was tempted to remove, but decided a few lines was worth the assurance one definitely won't end up pasting an image where it doesn't belong. Coincidentally, [I wrote a handler](https://gist.github.com/ChristoferK/d0e0f577ecdba769ad3be48366975404) the other day for someone else to search all windows, optimising it so it doesn't need to iterate through a loop at all.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find the answer on another post on Stack Overflow. I have added the answer for anyone who comes across the same problem.

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
    delay 1
    keystroke "/path/to/file"
    delay 1
    keystroke return

    delay 1
    keystroke return

    delay 1
end tell
```

Comment: This works great, just be sure to allow Applescript to send keystrokes:  System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Accessibility